# Burninate the support tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Seems like people come to StackOverflow for support, no need to tag your question with support.

303 questions tagged [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support). Only time support would be valid, IMHO, is on Meta. It's almost like the persons tagged as they were talking:

Does Visual Studio (tag) Support (tag) C# (tag) or Should I Go to School (tag) ?

Comment: I'm almost tempted to edit in a support tag... but yeah, that list can do with some cleanup, closing and retagging.

Comment: Seems like a wiki summary would be a good start. The [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277386/free-live-chat-support-for-asp-net-website) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264010/ive-lost-an-app) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261748/how-to-calculate-confidence-from-support-in-java) use the support tag in three different ways (I am making a support site, I need support for FB, and a mathematical concept)

Comment: Edited to Support the Burninate tag ;)

Comment: @Guvante: I don't know about that for the same reason there is no programming tag.

Comment: @Guvante Why a summary? Do any of those question need the tag to begin with?

Comment: @Bart: I miss-read your comment and forgot to mark mine as in response to yours. Didn't realize burninate was the idea. Seemed to me that two of the examples I found made sense on their own.