# What does "support" (like in the "support" required tag in Meta) means on the SE network?

Tags: support, required-tags

The excerpt of [support](/questions/tagged/support) says

> A request for assistance with one of the site's features

Since SE network is about Q&A, by "assistance" I understand that a one-time intervention by other person is required, b/c privileges, not by providing knowledge in the form of a post.

When a user make a post, a question, asking for a description or for clarification on a SE site feature, IMHO, the post (question) is a *regular question*, there should not be be required a special tag.

By the other hand, considering that SE sites are [moderated by you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), me and everyone else, I think that [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is the better option between the mandatory tags for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

Related

- [Burninate the support tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170682/)  (unanswered)

  - This question is about the use of the support tag on Stack Oveflow, but the core idea is the same.

    > Seems like people come to >>> Stack Exchange meta sites <<< for support, no need to tag
    > your question with [support](/questions/tagged/support).
    >
    > `n` questions tagged support. Only one-time support would >>> should <<< be valid, IMHO, in Meta
- [What's the point of the Support tag if your question just ends up being closed as 'too localized'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182203/) 
  - This question is about an issue that the OP has with his/her browser, but the title beginning could be appropriate for this post: "What's the point of the support tag".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) is for "What does this feature do?" and "How do I do X?" questions about the Stack Exchange network or software. In other words, the problem you're trying to solve is one of not understanding how things currently work.

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is more for cases when you understand what the current situation is, but want to question it; it's for questions of the form "Why are things the way they are?", or "Feature X is causing unintended consequences, what can we do about it?".

A good contrast is to look at the most viewed questions in each tag. [support](/questions/tagged/support) has "[How does reputation work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)", "[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)", and "[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)". In every case, the answers are oriented towards someone who isn't used to the Stack Exchange network, aiming to get them up to speed on how things work here.

Meanwhile, [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) has "[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)" (not really an ideal example, because it's more borderline), "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)", and "[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)". These questions are mostly about policy, rather than about technical aspects; e.g. the second one isn't "How do I delete fluff from a post?" but "When should I delete fluff from a post?".

TL;DR: [support](/questions/tagged/support) is for questions that want facts in their answers, whereas [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is for questions that want opinions in their answers.

(Just in case I've misinterpreted the question: the tags in question are intended for meta sites, like here on Meta and on the sitewide meta sites, and as such their usage reflects that. Neither would really be appropriate somewhere like Stack Overflow, and questions along the lines of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) are offtopic on most non-meta sites.)